# Doing several HTTP requests in sequence

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I do multiple http requests, so for this scenario how can I do another request `budgetService.getData()` after the `getBudgetDays()` requests completes?

```
this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate).pipe(
  catchError(res => this.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(this.startDate, this.finishDate)),
).subscribe(res => {
  // res = value of getBudgetDays if no error, or getBudgetDates if there is one
});
```

Comment: This should be already answered in any of the links above. If it doesn't let me know and I'll reopen question.

Comment: some answers use switchMap, concatMap, mergeMap. Which one should I use?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Probably `concatMap` or `mergeMap` I guess.

Comment: Also have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153902/angular-interval-pipe-with-a-longer-task-inside/53154900#53154900 for what's the difference